# Can MS Word automatically insert spaces between conjoined (pasted) words intelligently?

Tags: microsoft-word, dictionary

I'm pasting selected portions from a few different PDFs into MS Word, and in some cases entire sentences get pasted together as one word without spaces in between (eg: whatImeanistextlikethis). Manually inserting spaces between every single word gets exhausting.  Is there any built-in way or a plugin to automatically do such a thing? MS Word obviously knows what words are supposed to be, from its dictionary, so I'm hoping there's a plugin or macro out there that utilizes this to do an intelligent splitting.

**Update:** I've now tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, Paste Text Only, Paste Special (Unformatted Text) and Paste Special (Unformatted Unicode Text), with no difference. Pasting into plain old notepad also pastes the words clumped together.

**Update2:** Here's some relevant links for anyone else looking into splitting words automatically:

- [**How can I split multiple joined words?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195010/how-can-i-split-multiple-joined-words/)
- [**Word Split ~ A text segmentation tool**](http://whitemagicsoftware.com/software/java/wordsplit/)
- [**Warrior Forum ~ software to separate words?**](http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/520375-software-separate-words.html)

Comment: Yes, Word does recognize words spelled similar to those stored in it's dictionary, and tries to guess what you mean. In the case you described, I seriously doubt it can differentiate the words within a sentence without spaces. It likely sees it as one big misspelled word. Are the words together in the PDF? If not, you might want to try a different way to paste them into Word.

Comment: No, the words aren't together in the PDF, but come out together when copied and pasted. Could you give me an example of a different way to paste them?

Comment: You've not shared what method you are using now; context menu, Ctrl+V, menu, text only, merged format, etc. There are many methods to go about it. Tell us what you've tried. And without having the PDF file, I can not try anything to tell you what will work. You might want to post a link to the file if it doesn't contain any private information.

Comment: I've now tried Ctrl-V, Paste Text Only, Paste Special (Unformatted Text) and Paste Special (Unformatted Unicode Text), no difference. Pasting into plain old notepad also pastes the words clumped together. The PDF cannot be shared though, I'll look into writing a macro myself to do this. (And of course will update with an answer if I do manage it!)

Comment: I'd suggest using OCR to capture the text from the PDF. It will save you a lot of time and frustration trying to write a macro that will know where to separate the words.

Comment: Have you tried another PDF viewer to copy from?  Fixing the problem of non-spaced text would be quite hard and error prone.

Comment: Have you tried saving the PDF as a .docx file?

Comment: @Karen927 How do I do that?

Comment: If you have Adobe Pro, you can save PDFs as Word files (just select "save as" and choose the Word extension).  If you don't have it, you could find a relatively cheap license for version 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Note: It's been two years since this question was asked, but I also have (had) this problem as of writing

---

This solution requires Google Chrome (and the built-in PDF plugin)

---

1. Open the PDF in Google Chrome (eg. drag and drop the file into Google Chrome)
2. Highlight the text you want to copy
3. Copy the text (eg. through context menu)
4. Paste the clipboard contents into a text editor (in your case Microsoft Word)
5. Replace all the parentheses (or whatever character is in between the words) with a space

---

---

Text copied from PDF: `what)I)mean)is)text)like)this`
Text with parentheses replaced with spaces: `what I mean is text like this`

Note that if there are parentheses in the original text (ie. from the PDF), special precautions need to be taken

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're looking for, but honestly I'm in doubt of such a script/plugin/macro based on the complexity of the operation you want... luckily I'm confident there's a simpler solution. I'm not expert on the matter but I'm certain Word is incorrectly interpreting the formatting of the text. I would paste into notepad first, see if the spacing is correct there, then paste THAT into Word.

Comment: If the process that produced the PDF has done "spacing" by setting the horizontal starting point for each word, then I suspect a copy/paste would not inject spaces.

Comment: On that note, you might want to try an OCR option then which might do the trick.

Comment: Pasting into notepad and pasting "Text Only" in Word both result in the same thing, wordsarestillclumpedtogether.